Вставка изображений в docx файл на pythone
Стоит задача генерации отчетов в Word из PDF карточек, не могу победить вставку изображения.
Изображение нужно вставить с конкретными параметрами. Проблемы возникли с позицией и обтеканием текста. Самые удачные попытки не меняли обтекание, а картинка вставлялась то в конец, то в новый абзац.
Мне же нужно, что бы верхняя граница изображения была на уровне определенной строки, сама картинка была у левого края документа, а текст обтекал изображение вокруг рамки.
Пробовал следующие варианты
par = doc.paragraphs[2] 
par.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.LEFT
run = paragraph.add_run()
run.add_picture(img_path, width=Cm(5))

А так же вот так
par = doc.paragraphs[2] 
run = par.add_run()
run.add_picture(img_path)
run_element = run._r

anchor = OxmlElement('wp:anchor')
anchor.set('wrapText', 'bothSides')
anchor.set('distT', '0')
anchor.set('distB', '0')
anchor.set('distL', '0')
anchor.set('distR', '0')

extent = OxmlElement('wp:extent')
extent.set('cx', '3000000')
extent.set('cy', '2000000')
anchor.append(extent)

run_element.append(anchor)

При этом сам текст попадает в документ следующим образом, и менять либу docx-python,которая его превращает в нужный вид, не хотелось бы.
    search_text = 'Пример'
    index = find_paragraph_index(doc, search_text)
    doc.paragraphs[3]._element.addnext(doc.add_paragraph()._element)
    doc.paragraphs[4].add_run(doc.paragraphs[index+1].text+":"+" "+doc.paragraphs[index + 2].text)
    doc.paragraphs[index + 1].clear()

Итоговый результат должен быть примерно такого вида
Может кто либо сталкивался с подобным или знает решение. Заранее благодарен.

